# PHP - Passing sessions between folders

Tags: php, session

I have a simple script that sets the currency using a php session variable, however as soon as it returns the user to the directory they were in before, the session is no longer set..

(this script is located in the root folder /index.php)

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST[product_currency])) {
    $postCurrecy =  $_POST[product_currency];
    session_destroy();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION[currency] = $postCurrecy;
    echo $_SESSION[currency].' = '.$_POST[product_currency];
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;URL=$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]'>";
    die();
}
?>
```

The folder it returns to is /products/ which contains this:

```
<?php if (empty($_SESSION[currency])) { echo 'uh oh'; } else { echo $_SESSION[currency]; } ?>Currencies:                    
<form id="select-form" action="/" method="post">
<select class="inputbox" name="product_currency" size="1"  >
<option value="EUR" >€ Euro</option>
<option value="USD" selected="selected">$ US Dollar</option>
<option value="GBP" >£ GBP</option>
</select>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Change" />
</form>
```

`$_SESSION[currency]` returns 'uh oh' because it's empty :(

Comment: You need to call `session_start()` at the top of _all_ scripts which access the session.  Also, please quote your array keys as in `$_SESSION['currency']`

Comment: Ahh, that worked :D ty,
it always works fine without the quotes, so I don't see why I should add them

Comment: You should add them because a bunch of warnings are being thrown each time you don't, but if you have error_reporting turned off you don't see them. It is bad practice -- array keys are ints or strings, but if you don't quote them PHP will see them as undefined constants and kindly convert them to strings for you.  Poor practice to rely on it, and can actually cause collisions with real defined constants.

Comment: @King - you should add the quotes because you're just adding overhead to your scripts, slowing them down: PHP assumes that you're referencing a constant if you don't use quotes, tests for the existence of a constant, finds there isn't one, issues a warning... then decides you meant a string instead, and gets it right... cut out all that overhead, and quote the array key as a string in the first place so that PHP doesn't have to go through all that extra work before deciding you meant that the key was a string.

Comment: Oh.. didn't know that.. I never got a warning and I have error reporting set to all :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Credit for this answer should go to @Michael Berkowski*

You need to call `session_start()` at the top of *all* scripts which access the session.